# Solr delete won't work after schema update

Tags: solr, solrnet

I'm using SolrNET to post documents to the Solr index, as well as remove documents from the index.

This has been working until now.

What I've done is this:

- In schema.config, added a string field (this new field stores a GUID) instead of the earlier UUID field
- Restarted Tomcat

(I switched from the UUID field to string field because it didn't work well for me, but that's another story.)

Here is what my schema.config looks like:

```
<fields>
      <field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
      <field name="searchobjecttype" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
      <field name="heading" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" />
      <field name="body" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" />
      <field name="locationid" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
      <field name="currentlocationid" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
      <field name="countryid" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
      <field name="currentcountryid" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
      <field name="forumroom" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
        <field name="forumtopicid" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
      <field name="dt" type="date" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" />
      <field name="txt" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
      **<field name="guid" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />**
  </fields>
      <copyField source="id" dest="txt" />
      <copyField source="searchobjecttype" dest="txt" />
      <copyField source="heading" dest="txt" />
      <copyField source="body" dest="txt" />
      <copyField source="locationid" dest="txt" />
      <copyField source="currentlocationid" dest="txt" />
      <copyField source="countryid" dest="txt" />
      <copyField source="currentcountryid" dest="txt" />
      <copyField source="forumroom" dest="txt" />
      <copyField source="forumtopicid" dest="txt" />
      <copyField source="dt" dest="txt" />
      **<uniqueKey>guid</uniqueKey>**
      <defaultSearchField>txt</defaultSearchField>
      <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND" />
```

This query worked before:

```
var q = solr.Query(Query.Field("id").Is(item.Id.ToString()) && Query.Field("searchobjecttype").Is(item.SearchObjectType));

solr.Delete(q);
solr.Commit();
```

While it won't work now.

When debugging, I can see that the query matches documents (the NumFound property returns more than 0 when the query finds items). However nothing is deleted.

When I try to delete the same document through Solr's web interface, it works.

What am I missing? :)

Cheers and thanks.

Comment: why didn't the UUID field work?

Comment: It did "work", however, I couldn't delete documents from the live index - but it worked on my local computer. Hence my workaround I'm going to test now.. Just an alternative solution to see if the problem can be solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the guid field to `string` type (you'll have to reindex). The `text` field type probably does some analysis and you don't want to analyze this kind of data, you want to index it verbatim.